# How to use switch case statement and update API automatically?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React native.

I am trying to show Bus time to arrive at 6 stations meaning I have to put 6 API codes.

I actually implement only one API code, but if I use 6 API codes, I might have to use switch case statement, which I do not know how to make it...

And the other problem is that the bus time is not automatically updating.
For example, if bus time to arrive is 9:26, after 9:26, it is not changed, it is still indication of that bus would arrive at 9:26, although 9:26 was already passed.

This is my code,

```
export default class App extends React.Component {   
 constructor(){
super()
this.state = {
  name: [],
  name1: [] ,
  API:"",
componentWillMount(){

return fetch('https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/01000053207/live.json?app_id=d7180b02&app_key=47b460aac35e55efa666a99f713cff28&group=route&nextbuses=yes')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
for(var x in responseJson.departures){
this.setState({
state : this.state["name"].push(responseJson.departures[x][0]),
state : this.state["name1"].push(responseJson.departures[x][0]["line"],": ",responseJson.departures[x][0]["aimed_departure_time"]," ")

});
}

render() {


 return (

 <MapView.Marker
   coordinate={{
    latitude:77.232,
    longitude: -44.292,
   }}
   title={'A Station'}
   description={this.state.name1.toString().replace(/,/gi, "")}
   image={require('./bus.png')}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I understand what you're trying to do.

I don't think you need a switch statement to update data for each bus. Consider changing your data model so that it is a key:value pair of the busID you pass into the API and the value being an object of data related to that busID.

```
const busAPIs = [
    bus1: 'https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/01000053207...',
    bus2: 'some other API',
    ...
]  

this.state = {
     buses: [];
}

for(bus in busAPIs) {
 return fetch(busAPIs[bus])
...
.then
...
this.setState({bus: responseJson.departures});
```

Comment: Thanks :), I am just wondering If the data from API is updating automatically, what should I do .. ?